# python 3.6 rounds up decimal calculations automatically to 1 or -1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am encountering the following issue with python 3

```
erg = (545-1023)/25971
erg = -1
```

in the link below is a screenshot.

I don't encounter this problem if I run my code on a different machine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGi75.jpg

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide code examples by using the code format markup

Comment: Are you sure that's Python 3.6? That's the behaviour I'd expect from Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're on Python 3 when you get -1? That was the old behavior from Python 2. Try this:

```
from __future__ import (print_function, division)
erg = (545-1023)/25971
print(erg)  # -0.018405144199299218

import platform
print(platform.python_version())  # what's here? Python 2.x? Or 3.x?
```

Comment: this import is changing my results! fantastic

Comment: i am confused because the platform.pythonversion shows 2.7.1 but my ipython kernel in jupyter shows 3

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you would, please mark mine as the answer to your question. Also, were you on Python 2 accidentally?

Comment: Without more information, I'm not sure I can say for sure, but Jupyter used to be ipython notebook, and still (for now) will let you launch using `ipython3 notebook`. Try `ipython3` and see how that works out for you. If it doesn't, ask another question on SO and provide the details and I bet you get the answer.